# Do I need to wait for propagation for a CNAME record addition in AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, cname

Through the api for Amazon AWS Route 53 I'm adding a new CNAME record to an existing zone. I want to test to see if the record was added correctly.

Do I need to wait for propagation? Or since its a new record will it be grabbed immediately?

I saw an article which mentioned waiting for it to propagate but it was for creating a whole new zone; which I do not have to do since im adding it to an existing one.

The use case is I could be adding these (CNAME Records) on the fly and need to check to make sure they were added correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things: the delay between your updates on your provider web based interface and the change on all Route53 authoritative nameservers on one side, and on the other side after the change in authoritative nameservers the delay for all recursive nameservers in the world to be aware. The first case depends only on Amazon infrastructure. But you can query its authoritative nameservers and see if the resource is published. The second case is not really a propagation, and depends on TTLs and negative TTLs.

So I will focus more on the second case.

The methodology is simple:

1. start by querying the authoritative nameservers for your resource, double check they reply correctly. You can even use online troubleshooting tools for that: https://zonemaster.net/ and https://graphviz.net/
2. after that it is time to check recursive nameservers around the world.

First, a bit of terminology. Everyone uses that term, but "propagation" is wrong in the context of DNS. Because when you change something on the authoritative nameservers they do not push their changes top down to all other recursive nameservers in the world, as it would be just impossible.
On the contrary, recursive nameservers will "at some point" (it depends both on the zone content, state of their cache, and local policies), after a query redirected to them (except rare cases of upfront automated cache renewals) contact again one of the authoritative nameserver and pull the newest data.

So, you can start querying some "well known" open recursive nameservers to see what they learned for your resource: `1.1.1.1`, `8.8.8.8`,  or `9.9.9.9`, besides your own local ones (running on your own servers or using your ISP one), and it may be useful to use more than one as their caches will be in different states which will impact the results as explained above.

Here are some details on what happens exactly when you query a specific recursive nameserver for your resource:

- if its cache is completely empty for your domain/resource (for example it was just rebooted) it will immediately query the authoritative nameserver for the info, hence your change is immediately visible to it and all its clients
- this resource will be cached by the nameserver based on the TTL given by the authoritative one. "Normally" this is the **maximum** amount of time the record will stay in the recursive cache during which it will not query again the authoritative nameservers to check if something has changed. Two important points: one, the consensus is that the standards mandate it to be a maximum value, so caches are free to be cleared before it (for example space constrained caches may wish to evict oldest entries to make some space); two, it is known that some nameservers and/or nameservers deployments will alter the TTL value, for whatever local policy, so they may extend it for example if they deem it as being too low (it is considered in a way to be against the standard but that case exists as well as people putting TTLs as low as 1 or 5 seconds which is just as silly)
- now, another important case that often baffles people, especially those testing. If you add a new resource in your zonefile but query for its existence just before the change, the authoritative nameservers will reply with NXDOMAIN ("this resource does not exist") and this information will also be cached by recursive nameservers, for an amount of time called "negative TTL" (it is still a positive number acting as a delay, but called negative because it applies to negative replies such as "this resource does not exist). So in a way you "pollute" the cache because if you do the changes in your authoritative nameservers and just after query your recursive one again, it will still reply "no such resource" because it has this information in its cache.

So the key point is always to clearly separate tests on authoritative vs recursive nameservers and to be fully aware of the properties attached to a recursive cache.

Answer (score 0):

Route53 is a distributed DNS management system. When you create a new CNAME or any record set within a Hosted Zone, it needs to be propagated to distributed servers running in AWS edge locations. This can take few seconds to few minutes.

Note: The creating propegation of a record set differs from updating. This is because even after the update, the old record set could live up to the TTL value defined in the external caches.